# Знак вопроса в переменной в location

Tags: регулярные-выражения, nginx, pcre, location

Есть ссылка вида:
`https://site.com/testdir/https://site2.com/testdir2/addparam?id=1234qwert`
Нужно выдрать из неё `id`.

Пробую:

```
location ~/testdir/https://site2.com/testdir2/addparam?id=(.*)$ {
  return 307 https://site2.com/$1;
}
```

Не работает.
Пробую так:

```
location ~/testdir/https:/(.*)$ {
  return 307 https://site2.com/$1;
  add-header out-head-param $1;
}
```

И вижу, что запрос возвращает мне только часть `url`: `site2.com/testdir2/addparam`.

Куда подевался `?` с параметром?
Как получить желаемый результат?

Comment: попробуйте `return 307 https://$host$request_uri;`

Comment: @RifmaMan `$host` вернёт `site.com`, а `$request_uri` вернёт полный `url` запроса, т.е. `/testdir/https://site2.com/testdir2/addparam?id=1234qwert`

Comment: Прошу прощения, не так понял вопрос

Comment: В $arg_id, но в целом идея дурацкая. У вас уже потерялся двойной слеш, например

Comment: @AlexeyTen, я понимаю, что он потерялся, писал как получил. `$arg_name` работает, спасибо большое.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, а можете рассказать, почему идея дурацкая? Или дать ссылочку на чтиво.